# Change color of clicked button AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I made a simple puzzle game in ROBLOX and I've decided to re-make it in AS3.

I've created a grid of buttons with click events, and now I need to change their color when clicked. I've currently got this:

```
        trace("Button clicked:", event.currentTarget.id);
        event.currentTarget.graphics.beginFill(0xA00000)
        event.currentTarget.graphics.endFill()
```

the trace prints fine but the color doesn't change (causes no errors either)

The buttons are movie clips with labels inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beginFill` and `endFill` are used to control the filled color of drawing commands like `drawRect`, they don't just change the fill of any arbitrary display object.

To change the color of a display object you can use [`ColorTransform`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html):

```
var colorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
colorTransform.color = 0xA00000;
DisplayObject(event.currentTarget).transform.colorTransform = colorTransform;
```